# Texto em inglês ao marcar resposta como aceita

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao marcar resposta como aceita, a prorpiedade title da img está em inglês conforme imagem.

A tradução talvez seria:

> Clique para marcar esta como a melhor resposta; Clique novamente para
>   alternar

Alguém tem uma sugestão?

Desculpe se estou publicando isto na área errada, caso não seja aqui, por favor onde devo inserir este tipo de falha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We missed a view that contains this title when were localizing the page. The translated version will be with you shortly.